# the relationship between convergence and topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I found the following in a textbook:

The topology in $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is defined by:

If $\{\varphi_\nu\}$ satisfies that for all compact sets $K$ and for all multi-indices $\alpha$, $\sup_{x\in K}|\partial^\alpha \varphi_\nu|\to 0$, then we call $\varphi_\nu\to 0$.

---

I don't understand why it defines a topology by convergence, to be more concrete, what's the open sets of $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ according to the definition above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a metric space you can define the closure of a set $A$ as the set of limit points of all convergent sequences of $A$. In general topologic spaces this does not work unless you replace "sequence" by "net". Using $\nu$ as an index suggests your textbook is talking about nets and not sequences so in this case it would indeed define a topology by net convergence.

You can find more details here: [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/convergence.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf). Proposition 3.1. is what you need.